# Reset ASP.NET Identity Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which uses ASP.NET Identity. I want to add a feature which resets the database. Here is the layout of the database used by Identity right now

[image]

I've created a controller that will contain the code to reset the database

```
public ActionResult GenerateDatabase()
{
    //Drop all tables
    //Readd all tables
    return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
}
```

But I'm fairly new to working with SQL Server through C#. How can I reset the database through a C# controller (as in drop the tables and readd them)?

Comment: Just simply use ADO.Net SqlCommand with the correct SQL Query to drop the database. Then you need to tell the DbContext to recreate the database if not exists.

Comment: Can you post code that would recreate the database as it is right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all you want via the `Database` property of your `DbContext` :

To delete the database just use:

```
yourDbContextInstance.Database.Delete();
```

To recreate the databse just use:

```
yourDbContextInstance.Database.Create(); // Also check CreateIfNotExists()
```

Comment: Does that recreate it with all the tables needed for Identity as shown in my image?

Comment: Yep. It will create all tables that are mapped in your DbContext. The identity entities are known by by the context then it will create them.

Comment: Awesome, unfortunately though it throws this error 
Cannot drop database "aspnet-VDNA-20161028113006" because it is currently in use.

Comment: Just make sure you're not using Sql Server Manangement Studio with some of the tables openned or something like that.